# How to import the google api client into python so that it runs with as a cronjob?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, cron

I am trying to use the google API client to download something every day for something but I have deduced that for some reason it won't let me import googleapiclient when I run it in crontab.
For example, if I run this in crontab
crontab: `* * * * * python3 test.py >> cron.log`

test.py:

```
print("Hello")
```

cron.log outputs:

```
Hello
```

But if I then once I import it so the file look like this

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
print("Hello")
```

then the cron.log looks like this:

Its just empty. I can not figure out why this is true. The google API client I believe is installed correctly because when I run it manually then it works perfectly with no issues.
The operating system I am using is macos.

Comment: Try `python3 test.py 2>&1 >> cron.log`

Comment: @S3DEV Tried that and it is still outputting nothing in the log file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I fixed it is first by changing the crontab to `python3 test.py > cron.log 2>&1`. This showed that the errors where. Then I realized that it was not able to import googleapiclient into python. I still did not understand why it does not, but a workaround I found was to first install the libraries into a folder and then accessing the libraries from there.
To install the libraries into a folder the command I used in terminal is below:

```
pip3 install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib -t ./lib
```

Then inside the python I added whats below to the beginning of the file so it would know where to import the libraries from.

```
import os
import sys
file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
module_path = os.path.join(file_path, "lib")
sys.path.append(module_path)
```

This does work.